# Blank List returned when using XPath with Morningstar Key Ratios

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, request

I am trying to pull a piece of data from the morningstar key ratio page for any given stock using XPath. I have the full path that returns a result in the XPath Helper tooldbar add-on for google chrome but when I plug it into my code I get a blank list returned.

How do I get the result that I want returned? Is this even possible? Am I using the wrong approach?

Any help is much appreciated!

Piece of Data that I want returned:

AMD Key Ratios Example:

[image: AMD Key Ratios Example]

My Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os.path
import sys
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AMD&region=USA&culture=en_US')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
rev = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]')
print(rev)
```

Result of code:

[]

Desired result from XPath Helper:

[image: XPath Result]

Thanks,
*Not Euler*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those pages that downloads much of its content in stages. If you look for the item you want after using just `requests` you will find that it's not yet available, as shown here.

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AMD&region=USA&culture=en_US'
>>> page = requests.get(url).text
>>> '5,858' in page
False
```

One strategy for processing these pages involves the use of the selenium library. Here, selenium launches a copy of the Chrome browser, loads that url then uses an xpath expression to locate the `td` element of interest. Finally, the number you want becomes available as the `text` property of that element.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get(url)
>>> td = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//th[@id="i0"]/td[1]')
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f436b07c27742abb36b262639245801f", element="0.12745670001529863-2")>
>>> td.text
'5,858'
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain the issue in a clear and simple manner Bill Bell. I greatly appreciate it. Do you know how often I can call morning star using requests.get?

Comment: You're very welcome. I regret I can't tell you how often you can hit their server. In fact, this was the first time I saw one of their pages. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

As the content of that page is generated dynamically so you can either go through the process as Bill Bell shows already, or you can grab the page source then apply css selector on it to get the desired value. Here is an alternative to xpath:

```
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AMD&region=USA&culture=en_US')
tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
rev = tree.cssselect('td[headers^=Y0]')[0].text
print(rev)
```

Result:

```
5,858
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply Shahin! Your answer proved successful and I thank you for taking the time to help me out! Do you know how often you can call driver.get on a website or tree.cssselect on a certain page? Is there a limit to how much you can pull from a page once you use driver.get?